# Java - 1 more step to complete program (homework)

Tags: java

My last step involves getting the integer percent of the sum. 
So if I enter:
2
1
1
2
The output should be:
2, which is 33.333% of the sum.
1, which is 16.666% of the sum.
1, which is 16.666% of the sum.
2, which is 33.333% of the sum.

Since I am very new to arrays, I am extremely puzzled. I don't understand how to get the percent since user can enter any amount of integers. If it was only 2 integers, just say 2 and 2, they each would be 50 percent

```
import java.util.Scanner;
   public class Integers {
   /* program 7-1*/
      public static void main(String[] args) 
      {
         Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
         System.out.println("How many numbers will you enter?");
         int size = keyboard.nextInt();
         int[] entry = new int[size];

         System.out.println("Enter " + entry.length + " integers, one per line:");

         int sum = 0;
         for (int index = 0; index < entry.length; index++)
         {
            entry[index] = keyboard.nextInt();
            sum +=  size;
         }

         System.out.println("The sum is " + sum + "." + "\nThe numbers are:" );         
      }
   }
```

Comment: Note**The integers are entered on separate lines

Comment: Can you clarify exactly how you're puzzled and exactly where you're stuck? All I see so far is a requirement and code, with no attempt at explanation. A good rule of thumb: put as much effort into asking your question as you'd want someone to put in answering it.

Comment: @jaielob Now edit your question with the additional information so people don't have to read all the comments and go back and delete any obsolete comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now that you have all entries and the sum, you are almost there:

- You need another loop to go over entries one at a time
- To calculate percentage, multiply the entry by `100.0`, and then divide by the `sum`. Note the dot zero at the end of `100.0` - it's there on purpose
- If you are on Java 5 or later, a very convenient way of printing out a number followed by percentage sign is [`printf`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#printf%28java.util.Locale,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...%29). Note, however, that the percent sign `%` needs to be *escaped*.

Answer (score 1):

What answer are you getting that's incorrect?  That's what is puzzling.  I looked at your code, but I don't see any division, percentage calculation, or output.

I compiled and ran your code.  Here's the output I got.  So far, so good.  What's wrong?  What's your question?

```
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_02\bin\java" -Didea.launcher.port=7533 "-Didea.launcher.bin.path=C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 120.11\bin" com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain cruft.Integers
How many numbers will you enter?

4
Enter 4 integers, one per line:
2
1
1
2
The sum is 16.
The numbers are:

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Write more code.  Be careful to remember that integer division isn't what you want; percentages need to be doubles.

```
int x = 1/2;  // x will equal zero.  know why?
```

You've already calculated the sum.  You know that if you take in ten numbers, no matter how many or what their values are, the percentage of the sum that each one will represent is the number divided by the sum.  Is that what you're asking?

1 hour later:

It's been a whole hour, and you seem to think that writing comments is more educational than actually writing the four lines of code that you need.  Okay, I'll bite - here's your solution.  I'll risk the wrath of all those who will be outraged by someone who does homework.  I want you to see how ridiculous it is that you wouldn't even attempt *four lines of code*:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Integers {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("How many numbers will you enter?");
        int size = keyboard.nextInt();
        int[] entry = new int[size];
        System.out.println("Enter " + entry.length + " integers, one per line:");
        int sum = 0;
        for (int index = 0; index < entry.length; index++) {
            entry[index] = keyboard.nextInt();
            sum += entry[index];  // this was wrong - I fixed it.
        }
        // This is all you had to do. 
        for (int anEntry : entry) {
            System.out.println(String.format("value: %d %6.2f%%", anEntry, anEntry * 100.0 / sum));
        }
        System.out.println(String.format("total: %d %6.2f%%", sum, 100.0));
    }
}
```

Comment: After "the numbers are" I need to output the percent of each interger as so: 2 is 33.333% of the sum.... and so forth. My trouble is how to achieve this with an x amount of integers in an array

Comment: So...give it a try and see how it goes.  Don't just fish for someone to do your assignment for you.  Strap on your big boy pants and try something.

Comment: I have. I can do it if I know exactly how many integers it will be, but since the user can enter any amount im stuck

Comment: And you have any number of values in the array....you need another loop after the first one, right?

Comment: But you're already reading the correct number of integers, don't you think there should be some kind of similarity between reading and performing a calculation a certain number of times?

Comment: How many numbers?  entry.length, perhaps?  You do know how many.

Comment: Why, thank you for reading.  I don't think that's rude; you're being too sensitive.  My suggestion is an honest one, even if you don't like the language: *do something*.  Let's see your best attempt.  You'll learn more by trying than you will waiting for someone to break down and do it for you. Aren't the comments enough of a hint to try it?  Please, edit your answer with your best attempt.

Comment: I understand where your coming from. My professor won't email me back with my questions and this is an online class which is a mistake since I can't raise my hand when I don't understand something. Just gets a little frustrating. I know kids post here looking for somebody to do it for them, but that's not me. I have enough suggestions here to figure it out for myself. I really like java so far, just takes a min to sink in. Thank you for posting!

Comment: LOL sorry duffymo I needed a break from coding and got caught up here since I've only been a member for a few days now. I understand I need a for loop and get that, but am unfamiliar with the String.format, and the value part. And whats the anEntry all about?

Comment: Found my answer on Oracle. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Since this is not homework, I am not going to give you an answer, but give you an approach that you can figure out to implement (and learn from :-D)

create two arrays of the length the user enters and one counter for the second. the first array will be the one you currently have. The second will store unique values and the counter will represent how many unique values are in that array. When the user enters a value, check to see if its in the current array, if not add it to unique and increment the counter. Then iterate through the unique array at the end of your program performing the calculation.

--cheers

Comment: @dasblinkenlight 's answer is for if you need a percentage for each value entered, mine will work if you need a percentage for each UNIQUE integer entered. Between these two solutions you should be able to solve it either way :-D happy coding

Comment: Thank you! I think I know what i need to do now. Thank you for the friendly advise.

Comment: No problem @jaielob , if you have found any of our answers useful please choose a best answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you have an unknown number of integers separated by a ' ' space, you could take them in as a String and use the String.split function - you can find documentation at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String) - which will give you an array which is as large as you need it to be, and whose length is stored in the length field of the array.

Comment: This is the least of his problems.  His code already knows how many values were read in, even if he doesn't.